# datatables server side filtrar y ordenar

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo una situación con datatables usando server-side script

```
Table localidad
localidad origen
localidad destino
```

En **$joinQuery: (server-side)**

```
..
LEFT JOIN localidad GO ON A.mxv_loc_ori_fk = GO.loc_id
LEFT JOIN localidad GD ON A.mxv_loc_dest_fk = GD.loc_id
..
```

En **$columns:**

```
array(
       array( 'db' => '(`GO`.`loc_nombre`) as origen', 'dt' => "origen", 'field' => 'origen'),
       array( 'db' => '(`GD`.`loc_nombre`) as destino', 'dt' => 'destino', 'field' => 'destino' )

);
```

En **JS:**

```
"columns": [
    {"data":"origen"},
    {"data":"destino"}
]
```

Todo bien hasta este punto.
Las columnas muestran la info correctamente. El problema está cuando intento filtrar u ordenar, ahí es donde no funciona.

Comment: Deberias poner tu definicion del dataTable

Comment: Puedes probar el filtrado en tu base de datos y ver si trae algún valor null y de ser si la repuesta saber si tienes configurado como funcionaria  las columnas  cuando tengan un valor nulo.

Comment: Copio la respuesta de Allan, uno de los creadores de DT, por si a alguien le sirve:

Hi,

Unfortunately that isn't a feature that the demo SSP script provides at the moment. The script would need to be modified to add that feature.

Allan




https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/129980#Comment_129980

Answer (score 0):

Dejo mi resolución al problema por si alguien tiene el mismo inconveniente:

Crear una vista de la tabla a la que se está haciendo doble JOIN.
Ejemplo

```
CREATE VIEW localidad_vista (locv_id,locv_nombre,locv_prov_fk)
```

AS select loc_id,loc_nombre,loc_provincia_fk FROM localidad;

Entonces, podemos cambiar la consulta SQL. En vez de hacer doble JOIN a la tabla, hacemos un JOIN a la tabla para destino, y un JOIN a la vista para origen.

Por el momento parece funcionar bien, ya que tenemos dos nombres distintos para cada columna, y no necesitamos usar alias, que es donde Datatables no parece funcionar bien en el sort y filter.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Para orderdar y filtrar en datatable puedes asigarlo sobre la configuración global de la tabla.

```
seacrh: true,
sort: true,
columns: [
    {data:"origen"},
    {data:"destino"}
]
```

O lo puedes hacer con cada columna, dependiendo de tus necesidades.

```
columns: [
    {data:"origen", seacrh: true, sort: true },
    {data:"destino", seacrh: true, sort: true}
]
```

En cualquiera de los casos, default de [search](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) y [sort](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html) son true.

Comment: Esa no es la pregunta que yo hice. Por favor lee bien el post antes de responder.